# Have trouble with bitbucket git ssh key

Tags: git, bitbucket, ubuntu-server

I use official [docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html) to solve this problem.

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

don't open connection, i use

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

after add ssh key and all works, but when close terminal and run

```
git ls-remote
```

get an error

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

run as root user and not root

How can i solve this problem?

ssh config 
https://pastebin.com/GY5GJV3z

Comment: Have you added your key like so `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: of course, connection to bitbucket work greatly in current terminal session, but in new terminal session get this error

Comment: It might have something to do with your ssh config then. Can you post that?

Comment: upload on pastebin
https://pastebin.com/GY5GJV3z

Comment: maybe you added your key in wrong place? I had that issue many times, I added my ssh key as some thing like 'access key' or some other, but it wasn't place for key allowing you to manipulate repository

Comment: it can't be a wrong place, because in current terminal session all work and if i want to see list of ssh added keys in new terminal session, ssh-add -l, get en error:
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Comment: You might need to add something like: 
Host bitbucket.org
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: awesome, add bitbucket host and all work, please answer on question i accept it as right